# В консоли работает но в скрипте не работает

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Не полный код из js. этот кусок находится в функции которую я в html вызываю на onclick, по клику на кнопку другой обьект должен становиться больше, в моём случае это текст который можно раскрыть нажав на кнопку

Работает только вторая часть кода с elif*

**СРОЧНО НУЖНА ПОМОЩЬ**

```
if (p.classList.contains('moretoshow') === true) {
        p.classList.remove('moretoshow');
        u.textContent = 'далее...';
    }   else if (p.classList.contains('moretoshow') !== true) {
            p.classList.add('moretoshow');
            u.textContent = 'меньше...';
        }
```

Изменено:

```
let u = document.querySelector('.p_continue');
let p = document.querySelector('.p');
u.addEventListener('click', more);
function more() {
 
    if (p.classList.contains('moretoshow') === true) {
        p.classList.remove('moretoshow');
        u.textContent = 'далее...';
    }   else if (p.classList.contains('moretoshow') !== true) {
            p.classList.add('moretoshow');
            u.textContent = 'меньше...';
        }
}
```

Comment: Уберите сравнение в условиях, а во втором перед проверкой поставьте оператор отрицания !

Comment: Приведите [mcve] который продемонстрирует возникшую у вас проблему. В текущем виде показанный здесь код не будет работать вообще, потому что обращается к несуществующей переменной `p`, а откуда она должна существовать и вообще в каком контексте этот код выполняется - сейчас непонятно (в показанном коде нету никакого onclick, например)

Comment: консоль ошибок не выдаёт, думаю с получением  **p** и **u** всё нормально, но работает только вторая часть кода, даже если их поменять местами

Comment: @Elmir убрать ===?

Comment: @NoNick метод contains и так возвращает или true или false, уберите сравнение, оставьте только p.classList.contains('moretoshow'). Второй блок можете просто заменить на else. Если первый блок вернет false, выполнится второй блок

Comment: js - https://pastebin.com/s7RqherB

     css - https://pastebin.com/7VjRTseE

     html - https://pastebin.com/y6biA6Fd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вставь вот это, и проверь. Подправил моменты с условием и с вызовом функции.

```
let u = document.querySelector('.p_continue');
let p = document.querySelector('.p');
u.addEventListener('click', () => more());
function more() {
 
    if (p.classList.contains('moretoshow')) {
        p.classList.remove('moretoshow');
        u.textContent = 'далее...';
    }   else {
            p.classList.add('moretoshow');
            u.textContent = 'меньше...';
        }
}
```

Comment: Работает тоже только в консоли, думаю ошибка где то в html

Comment: кнопка на 24 строке

Comment: ошибок в вызове функции не вижу

Comment: @NoNick У меня всё работает. Вставил html и сss, Отрабатывает как нужно. Удалите с вашего html обработчики клика и тогда всё заработает.

Comment: попробую удалить

Comment: да, большое спасибо, помогли